# Qt creator I can't make my class become the recevier(slot)

Tags: qt, qt-creator

Recently,I use qt creator to develop some demo,but I meet some problems about the qt creator.When I add a class to my project and write the follow codes:

```
#ifndef BUTTONRECIVER_H
#define BUTTONRECIVER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <iostream>

class ButtonReciver : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ButtonReciver(QObject *parent = 0);

signals:

public slots:
    void button_click();
};

#endif // BUTTONRECIVER_H
```

But I can't make this class become slot(receiver) to receive button click signal,I use the qt creator to choose the receiver,but it does't exist in the list.Please help me.

Comment: A class cannot be a slot, it _contains_ slots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your button is called say **myButton**, then try something like:

```
ButtonReciver* receiver = new ButtonReciver(this);

connect(ui->myButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), receiver, SLOT(button_click()));
```

Put this someplace after **ui->setupUi(this)** in your form's constructor.

Usually, you just right click on the button and click "Go to slot...", and it will create a handler for you.

Comment: can I use qt creator ui edit to finish the above steps?I use qt creator 2.7,in ui panel,I see a signal and slot ui editor,But I don't know how to use it,because my ButtonReciver doesn't exist in the items of object whoes method is slot

Comment: The signal and slot editor would help you wire up different UI elements together, but I don't see how non-UI elements would work with that. If you had a QWidget-derived class, you could add a Widget in the UI editor and use "Promote to..." to promote it to your widget class, then wire it up with the signal and slot editor. In practice, I rarely use the signal and slot editor in the GUI... since I'm usually using "Go to slot..." to add handlers, or connecting to non-UI QObject-derived classes.